# Why isn't my background image being displayed in FXML

Tags: java, image, background, javafx, fxml

I decided that I wanted to start learning FXML and the first thing that I wanted to do is create a background Image. I've added background images in javafx before and I thought that the process of adding background images in FXML would what somewhat similar to what you would do in javafx. What am I missing?

Here is my FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="menu" spacing = "20" alignment="TOP_CENTER"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.MenulayoutFXMLController">
<StackPane> 
    <ImageView>
        <image>
            <Image url="@ImageFiles/BlueBackgroundColor.jpg" />
        </image>
    </ImageView>
</StackPane>
</VBox>
```

My main class in javafx

```
 public class MillionaireTriviaGame extends Application 
{  
@Override
public void start(Stage menuStage) throws Exception 
{
    Parent object = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MenulayoutFXML.fxml"));

    Scene menuScene = new Scene(object, 640, 480);

    menuStage.setTitle("Let's play who wants to be a millionaire");
    menuStage.setScene(menuScene);
    menuStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

My project directory(The project that I'm working with is MillionaireTriviaGame)

[image: Project Directory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project directory shows that your image folder is located in a folder `ImageFiles` which is not on the classpath. Due to this at runtime, the application is not able to find the image.

Move the folder `ImageFiles` into `src`, clean and build the project and try to run again.

Comment: And you can't do this in FXML? I've done it before in CSS but I want to try to do this in FXML

Comment: Well you can, can you add the location of your image and the fxml?

Comment: Sure I'll post a screenshot the project directory.

Comment: I've added my project Directory

Comment: Hey man one last thing. I added an audio files folder to the same location that the image folder is in. I tried to load an mp3 audio file like this  <MediaPlayer fx:id="gameIntro" autoPlay="true"volume="0.1">
      <media>
          <Media source="@AudioFiles/GameIntroTheme.MP3" />
      </media>
  </MediaPlayer> but that didn't work. What I can do?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.